# why my search code does not work on internet explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html, jqgrid

i have the following code for search from database show return result to the page and show them with jqgrid, my code works fine with  firefox but its not work on ie, when i use of utf8 
like arabic letters, i set both of encoding of ie, and firefox to unicode(utf8)

its html code

```
first name: <input type="text" id="firstname" onkeydown="doSearch(arguments[0]||event)" value="" class="mytextbox" /> 

<button onclick="gridReload()" id="submitButton" style="margin-right:100px;" class="Buttons">search</button>
```

my javascript code

```
function gridReload(){ 
    var name = jQuery("#firstname").val();

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post2.php?firstname="+firstname",page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");

}
```

and my php code

```
if(isset($_GET["firstname"]))
 $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];

mysql_query ( "set names utf8" );

if($firstname!='')
 $where= "  firstname LIKE '$firstname%'"; 

$SQL = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM  mytable ".$where." 
     ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";

 $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die(mysql_error());
$responce->page = $page;
     $responce->total = $total_pages;
     $responce->records = $count;
 $i=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
     $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
     $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array(
     $row[id],$row[firstname],$row[lastname]);
     $i++; 
     }

 echo json_encode($responce);
```

why its not work with ie(i teste with ie8) but works with opera and firefox

thanks

Comment: Define "works" vs "doesn't work".  What unexpected output are you getting in the IE case?

Comment: on ie its not find record,but on firefox it finds my search record and shows on jqgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have problem with quotes in the line where you use `setGridParam`. Probably you mean

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {url:"<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post2.php?firstname="+firstname,
     page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {url:"<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post2.php?firstname="+firstname",
     page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

It seems to me not good to build url with this code. You should at least use something like

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {url:"<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post2.php?firstname="
         +encodeURIComponent(firstname),
     page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

or

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {url:"<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post2.php?"+
         jQuery.param({firstname: firstname}),
     page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Then any international characters from the `firstname` will be encoded correctly in the url.

One more way is the usage of `postData` parameter of the jqGrid. See [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for example.

Comment: thanks for your reply , my problem is solved with jQuery.param function