# Get current url including parameters of Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, jqgrid

I am looking to get the full url of the last request to my ajax service made by JqGridincluding page, records per page, search params etc.

Is there any method or collection of methods within the JqGrid api I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jqGrid **don't save** somewhere the full URL appended with all parameters. So it is **not possibl**e within the jqGrid API archive this.

To see full URL you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or other close tool.

In general it is well known how the url will constructed. How I understand indirectly you want use HTTP GET (`mtype: "GET"`). I explain the construction of the URL in case of HTTP GET.

The full URL of the GET requests will constructed from:

- `url` parameter of the jqGrid
- `postData` parameter of the jqGrid
- some additional paremeters which depend on the action used (first grid load, data searching, paring and so on). The names of this additional parameters can be changed by `prmNames` parameter of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options#how_to_overwrite_global_options). For example if you define `prmNames: {sort: "searchIndex", order: "searchDirection", search: null, nd: null}` then parameters `sidx` and `sord` will be renamed to `searchIndex` and `searchDirection`. Parameters `_search` and `nd` will not send.

Below you find some typical urls:

1. baseurl?_search=false&nd=1250348761396&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
2. baseurl?_search=false&nd=1250348761396&rows=20&page=1&sidx=Name&sord=asc
3. baseurl?_search=true&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Name&sord=asc&searchField=Manufacture &searchString=Micro&searchOper=bw

The first url requests loading of the first page of data, 20 rows per page, no sorting. The second url has sorting by `Name`. The third url contain data filtering (with [simple searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching)) based on the filter "`Manufacture` begins with `Micro`" and sorting by `Name`. Results are paged by 10 rows per page and the first page are requested.

In case of using [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) or [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) instead of [Simple Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) the url will looks like a little other. Everithing are documented unter http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs. If you do have additional questions I'll can explain all more detailed.

It is important to understand that parameters used in URL should be encoded. So if you want **cunstruct url yourself** like

```
"baseUrl?firstName=" + myFirstName + '&lastName=' + myLastName
```

you should don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent` function to encode `myFirstName` and `myLastName`. Instead of that you can use `jQuery.param` (see [why my search code does not work on internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513175/why-my-search-code-does-not-work-on-internet-explorer/3513441#3513441)) or better use `postData` parameter of the jqGrid (see [jqgrid not updating data on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826478/jqgrid-not-updating-data-on-reload/2827032#2827032) and [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819)e). In the last case symbols '?' and '&' will be inserted in the url if it is needed and all data values will be encoded with respect of `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need and solved it with this:

```
var myUrl = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'url');
myUrl += "?myextraparam=something";
var postData = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
$.each(postData, function(key, value) {
  myUrl += "&"+key+"="+encodeURIComponent(value);
});
//alert(myUrl);
```

For me, the above got all I needed including items from the search toolbar if used. The `?myextraparam=something` should be replaced with any extra parameters you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer.  JQGrid will append to your query strings.

```
url: "/CaseManagement/Shipping/GetLastShipments?StudentID=" + GetSelectedStudentID(),
```