# Pagination not working for the json in JqGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid, pagination, for-loop

My pagination is not working when I removed the loadonce:true ...but if I use loadonce:true than my grid is not working. Any idea how can I get my pagination work again.

update: this is extension to [problem loading data in details jqGrid from master grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610173/problem-loading-data-in-details-jqgrid-from-master-grid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you remove `loadonce:true` and use `datatype:"json"` or `"datatype:xml"` jqGrid option then **your server** must implement pagination. The server receive some parameters which will be appended to the `url` in case of 'GET' requests or send in the HTTP body in case of "POST" requests. This parameters are `rows`, `page`, `sidx`, `sord`. For example if your table have a column with the index 'Name' as the current sort column and `rowNum: 20` then your url will be appended with `?rows=20&page=1&sidx=Name&sord=asc`. Your server should construct SELECT statement to the database where the data are placed with `ORDER BY Name asc` then divide the result in pages 20 rows per page and send back the first page of the results. (See [Get current url including parameters of Jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527617/get-current-url-including-parameters-of-jqgrid/3530191#3530191) for a little more information). For a PHP with MySQL on the server see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file as an example.

So in case of `loadonce:false` or no `loadonce` parameter **your server is responsible for sorting and paging of the data**. If it is not work you should verify your server code.

Comment: thanks! again...can I enable pagination without the change in server side by reseting 
setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 })) before trigger('reloadGrid');(as you suggested in previous qu without changing anything on server side....when I am making a call at onSelectRow ...

Comment: In my tests see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/verorange.htm, http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientSidePaging.htm, http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing.htm, http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing4.htm either there are no problem with paging or it could be fix with setting `rowNum` or `page` parameter.